# How to use mysql database with django_tenants?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-tenants

[django-tenants](https://django-tenants.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html)

When  i run migrations for tenant i got error

**Error : **

```
if connection.schema_name == public_schema_name:
AttributeError: 'DatabaseWrapper' object has no attribute 'schema_name'
```

I have tried to use below settings for database engine but it did not work

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_tenants.mysql_backend',
        # ..
    }
}
```

it was working fine for PostgreSQL db

```
     'default': {
         'ENGINE': 'django_tenants.postgresql_backend',
         # ..
     }
 }
```

I used below setting where i was getting error.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME':'portals',
        'USER':'root',
        'PASSWORD':'root',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306'
    }
}


MIDDLEWARE = [ 'django_tenants.middleware.main.TenantMainMiddleware',

]

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ( 'django_tenants.routers.TenantSyncRouter', )

TENANT_MODEL = "client.Client" TENANT_DOMAIN_MODEL = "client.Domain"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it currently only supports postgresql, because django-tenants relies on postgre's schemas to implement tenant functionality.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).